# Can I programmatily embed multiple views in RootView while using Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, storyboard, uitableview, xib

I'm trying to make multiple UITableView inside a UIScollView, using Paging to navigate between TableViews.

I can Drag, let's say 10 UITableView to UIScollView using Storyboard. and it's working, but the those UITableView are nearly look the same, and I have to set each TableView with different info. It's kind of tedious and inefficient.

What if I create a generic UITableView and controller using storyboard. and programatically generate and add 10 copys of it (with different content) to the UIScollView (which also created using storyboard)

***Can I do it using Storyboard, and How? or this can only be done using xib file?***

Comment: I would suggest to add UITableview inside collectionview and give paging and horizontal scrolling in UICollectionView. Also memory will be handled efficiently.

Comment: Is there any live examples? any app using the approach you talked about?

Comment: i have used this approach in my two of apps and they are on the verge of getting live

Comment: When doing this way, like you said. will it have the same app interface appearance and user experiences? I'm trying to create a app just like some other news apps, Panning around to navigate table views.

Comment: It will work smoothly.

Comment: WOW, That will be great. I will try it. Thanks Leena!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that I would suggest you programatically add or remove the table view as a subview, by creating a new instance of the table view each time, scrollViewDidScroll is called, ..
 Just do this make sure u have the array data for table view before hand and as soon as you add a tableview populate it with the respective data,….I had applied the same logic for a bunch of labels it worked for me.

Comment: Do you mean, it can't be done by storyboard? Maybe I can create instances of my existing UITableViewControler (which has corresponding UI element created using storyboard) ???

I really want to have an general idea of my user interface, just like storyboard provided.

Comment: It can be done through story board, What I am saying is dat make a new instance of table vie every time u scroll and populate it with the corresponding array data